# How to store id of selected row from table with angularjs and laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel

Below is my dropdown where on click of `withdrwal` user will get his all transactions till date from db.

```
<select id="test"  class="form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" ng-model="query.type" name="type" tabindex="1"> 
    <option value="2">Complaint</option>
    <option value="3">Withdrawl</option>                   
    <option value="4">Request</option>
    <option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
```

User will get all transactions in table format. I used Angular API's with metronic template.
Below is my table with checkbox of all transactions of user.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>       
            <th> Certificate No. </th>
            <th> Date </th>
            <th> Type </th>
            <th>Transaction ID</th>
            <th> Source </th>
            <th> Amount </th>
            <th> Amt </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd gradeX" ng-repeat="transactions in transactions track by $index">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="" /></td>
            <td><% $index + 1 %></td>
            <td></td>
            <td> <% transactions.type %> </td>
            <td><% transactions.id %></td>
            <td> <% transactions.source %></td>                     
            <td> <i class="fa fa-gbp" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;<% transactions.amount %> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" ng-model="query.amt"></td>         
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

my concern is to store selected rows `transaction id` and `Amt` in db.

My controller is like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{            
    $query = new Queries;                                
    $query->user_id = $request->userId;  
    $query->amt = $request->amt;                            
    $query->title = $request->title;
    $query->query_type = $request->type;
    $query->status_id = 2;
    $query->comments = $request->comments;
    $query->save();         
    if($query) 
    {
        return response()->json(['status_code'=>200,'status'=>'Success','response' => [] ,'message' => 'Query Info added successfully']);
    }
}
```

Right now i am unable to store data as per my concern. I want if i select only 2 rows from table then i want 2 rows in database to store with `amt` and transaction id`. If i input any`Amt` it by default goes to all rows.

Comment: This looks like AngularJS and not Angular?

Comment: @Alex right its angularjs